# Bad gateway 502, when ec2 machines are private

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have created an auto scaling group with EC2 machines. These EC2 machines have installed a webserver. The EC2 machines have a public IP adress and a load balancer in front of them. When querying the load balancer, I get a success message.

When creating the same scenario with no public EC2 machines for the EC2 machines, I get bad gateway 502. When I check the reachable analyzer, the ec2 machine is being reached.

Why is this the case? Is the public lb in a different network, so that I need an extra route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error. The webserver was not running, because in the user data I was trying to reach dockerhub and it could not reach it because my Ec2 machine is in a private network and that makes sense, because the reachable analyzer showed, that everything is right.